# Simple regular Expression I am not getting the output

Tags: android

I am not getting any output in logcat I have tried Log.v("dd",matcher.group(0)),  Log.v("dd",matcher.group(1)) and Log.v("dd",matcher.toString()); I dont know why is there any thing I have to change. How should I make the matcher to select the whole string "thingamabob"

```
try { 
    String ss="thingamabob";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ss);
    Log.v("dd",matcher.group()); 
}
catch(Exception e){ }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
     try{ 
            String ss="thingamabob";
             Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*");
             Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ss);
             matcher.matches();
             Log.v("dd",matcher.toMatchResult().group()); 
             }
             catch(Exception e){
           }
```

Comment: It say no match found

Comment: @VeeraPrasad im getting the answer dude for the above code. check again. filter the log and see or try to debug it

Comment: I get no sucessfull match so far

Comment: With debugger I get match=false

Comment: @VeeraPrasad add `matcher.matches();` before Log.V line